# Find an increasing function

Tags: functions

Find a monotonically increasing function such that it has same value for two or more different domain elements in a positive interval $x>0$ and also prove that the function is increasing.

Comment: A monotonically increasing function or a strictly monotonically increasing function? I think it should be impossible for the latter, and for the first just use $f(x)=0$

Comment: @Markus Zetto .Monotonically increasing function.But I don't understand when you say to use $f(x)=0$. Can you clarify a little more?

Comment: Increasing is defined as $f(x_1) \ge f(x_0)$ whenever $x_1 >x_0$, so $f(x)=0$ is a trivial example of an "increasing" function.  Here "increasing" means "not decreasing".

Comment: If the function was "strictly increasing", so $f(x_1)>f(x_0)$ when $x_1>x_0$, then the function cannot have the same value at two different points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let our domain $D$(a subset of the real numbers) have more than one element. Then the function $f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ mapping every element to $0$ does the trick: All elements are assigned the same value, and for $x,y \in D$ with $x\leq y$, also $f(x)=0 \leq f(y)=0$, so the definition of "monotonically increasing" is satisfied.

Comment: @ Markus Zetto.Yes, I get it. But what happen when you graph that function$f(x)=0$ . Can we tell just by looking at that graph that the function is increasing ? Should It not be a constant function?

Comment: As mjw hast stated above, the term "monotonically increasing" means only that the graph is not decreasing, so constant functions or functions that are constant on some domain are indeed included. However "stricly monotonically increasing" refers to only the functions that are increasing all the time, i.e. don't take on the same value twice.